# How to purge all the records from table "policy" without allowing rollback activity

Tags: sql

Purge the all records in SQL we use truncate option but it rolls back ..what is the SQL statement to purge all the records from policy travel without allowing rollback activity.Help is appreciated

Comment: Please specify **ONE** DBMS and remove wrong tag.

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different rdbms products with different features and different sql syntax. I removed the conflicting product tags (along with all unnecessary tags), pls add the one back that you use. Pls also explain what does roll back mean in your particular example - perhaps preventing the rollback or using the truncate in a way that it does not roll back provides a better solution than a simple delete statement. Btw, delete can be rolled back as well.

Comment: On a second thought, in mysql truncate table cannot be rolled back, so it is unlikely that you use mysql...

Comment: `truncate table policy; commit;`?

Comment: @Shadow what in case of oracle?

Comment: Are you using Oracle now?

Answer (score 0):

Just perform "truncate table policy;"